# What is the difference between Select Frame & Switch Window in RF?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, robotframework, ui-automation

I am new with working with RF, so my question is why i have to select frame after doing switch window and changing the main focus to the new window ,
is it necessary to do select frame when I can not use it ?

```
Switch Window    title:TestStack    30s
Select frame    frame id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `Select frame` after switching to another window, unless that other window has an iframe that you need to interact with. If it has an iframe, then you have to call `Select frame` just like you would in the main window.